# About the Errors in Finite Approximation

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, finite-differences, error-function, higher-order-logic

I am reading up on finite approximation recently[enter link description here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252586834_A_nearly_exact_second-order_finite-difference_time-domain_wave_propagation_algorithm_on_a_coarse_grid#fullTextFileContent), can someone help me explain why the author expressed the interval h as a sinusoidal function in this paper? And how did that come about?
Or I just don't understand this way of writing, for example, why the symbols s and k are associated with the interval h. [image]

Comment: This likely only works because the sine and cosine are combinations of exponentials, and exponentials transform sums into products. For any other type of function such a correction factor to the true derivative will be even more artificial.